# Why do all pages bar the home page turn up in Google?

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search, homepage

Our website is made with WordPress. The menu pages all turn up in Google searches, but the index page doesn't. The index page is absent; the others are there.

Why would this be?

Comment: Note that you site obviously *is* getting indexed. But to get more detail about the indexing, you should sign up for Webmaster Tools in the answer there, which also provides some further information. The homepage isn't being blocked for any obvious reason like a `noindex` meta robots tag, but it's also possible Google just finds it uninteresting at the moment.

Comment: You dont have to be sorry about using Wordpress. To me, it's an excellent CMS for small sites, with non-technical editors.